# I can not add a class to my <a> element, not javascript nor jquery (remove works!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, addclass

Seems like it is a big issue (adding classes). I went through numerous related question and yet I could not solve it. here is the javascript code. removing the class just works fine, but as you see I have tested multiple ways for adding the class which are not working!! I use firebug and it shows the removal of the classes, but nothing happens for adding class.
I would greatly appreciate your help.

I am using twitter bootstrap, when hovering on the links in any row of the table the badge is supposed to change to the new link. It removes, but not adds the badge class to the new link.

```
function setBadgeClass(theElement){
    classes = theElement[0].classList
    if (classes.contains("m_m_c5")){
        return "badge-inverse"
    }
    if (classes.contains("m_m_c3")){
        return "badge-info"
    }
    if (classes.contains("i_m_c5")){
        return "badge-important"
    }
    if (classes.contains("i_m_c3")){
        return "badge-success"
    }
}


function hoverImage(){
    $(".hoverImage").hover(
        function() {
            source = $(this).attr('href');
            target = $(this).attr('target');
            var image = document.getElementById(target);
            image.setAttribute("src", source);

            badgeClass = setBadgeClass($(this));

            //search for any other element with this badge class
            badgeDot = "." + badgeClass;
            badgedElement = $(badgeDot);
            //remove its two badge classes
            badgedElement.removeClass("badge");
            badgedElement.removeClass(badgeClass);
            //attach the badge class to the  theElement
            theElement[0].classList.addClass("badge");
            theElement[0].classList.addClass(badgeClass);
            //theElement.className += " badge";
            //theElement.className += " "+badgeClass;
            //d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
            //theElement.addClass("badge");
            //theElement.addClass(badgeClass);

        })
}


//as soon as the page is loaded...
window.onload = function (){
    hoverImage();
};
```

(part of) the Html is as follow.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="label label-inverse">CMIP5</th>
      <td>
        <a href="images_001/prec_001_CMIP5_Bias.rcp45.ANN.MultiModel.Max.nc.png" target="iframe_multi_model_5" class="m_m_c5     hoverImage badge badge-inverse"><small>Max </small></a>
        <a target="iframe_multi_model_5" href="images_001/prec_001_CMIP5_Bias.rcp45.ANN.MultiModel.Median.nc.png" class="m_m_c5     hoverImage"><small>Med </small></a>
        <a target="iframe_multi_model_5" href="images_001/prec_001_CMIP5_Bias.rcp45.ANN.MultiModel.Min.nc.png" class="m_m_c5 hoverImage    "><small>Min </small></a>
      </td>                     
    </tr>                  
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/linkhover2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you have a function called `setBadgeClass` that doesn't actually set anything? `getBadgeClass` would be more appropriate.

Comment: why operate on the classlist -> `theElement[0].classList.addClass("badge");` just use `theElement[0].addClass("badge");`

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't have 'var' when you are declaring variables like source, target, classes?

Comment: Also, `element.classList` doesn't have a `addClass` property, it's just `add`

Comment: @luk2302 remove the `[0]` in your comment's 2nd snippet

Comment: i don´t know what `theElement` is, maybe an array, therefore i intentionally left it there.

Comment: but, it's in the code. it's `$(this)`

Comment: theElement[0] doesn't exist in the scope of your hover. Change it to $(this).first().addClass(...);

Comment: There's just so much wrong here. Sorry @Luk2302, i didn't realize he was using theElement in the hover event too, that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: ah, you were looking above, i didn´t see it there^^

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry!! I had just forgotten to introduce theElement!! I used $(this)!
Thank you everyone for taking time and answering!!